# Else if always executing while reading from file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, contains

[SOLVED]

Fixed it by adding a marker for whether or not the statement was reached.

```
if(contains) // condition reached. marker "found" is 1.
    found = 1;
else if(found != 1){     // If found is not 1, not found. break.
System.out.println("Not found"); break;
```

---

Writing a program that involves reading an example SSN from a file. I'm trying to account for invalid input (that is, the string is not inside the file). However, the statements do not execute how I want them to. (Ignore everything but how my if statements are structured).

```
public static void getNameNum(String SocSec_input){
    try{
        reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\DEPARTMENT.txt"));
        reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\EMPLOYEE.txt"));

        /**
         * reads from employee text file
         */
        while((curr = reader2.readLine()) != null){
            /**
             * checks which lines contain user input and split the name from the code into storage
             */ 

            if(curr.contains(SocSec_input)){
                String[] parts = curr.split(",");
                String FNAME = parts[0];
                String LNAME = parts[1];
                String SSN = parts[2];
                String DNO = parts[9];

                if(SSN.equals(SocSec_input)){
                    while((curr = reader1.readLine()) != null){
                        /**
                         * searches the file for the user input
                         */
                        if(curr.contains(DNO)){
                            /**
                             * splits the line containing user input at each comma and store the values
                             */
                            String[] parts2 = curr.split(",");
                            String DNAME = parts2[0];
                            String DNUMBER = parts2[1];

                            if(DNUMBER.equals(DNO))
                                System.out.println(FNAME + " " + LNAME + " works in department " + DNO + ", " + DNAME);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // ALWAYS EXECUTING STATEMENT HERE*****************
            else if(!(curr.contains(SocSec_input))){
                System.out.println("Invalid SSN entered. We could not find
                                    that SSN in our database.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter the employee's SSN: 123
Invalid SSN entered. We could not find that SSN in our database.

Please enter the employee's SSN: 888665555
Invalid SSN entered. We could not find that SSN in our database.
--------------------
```

But 888665555 is in the file! What is going on?

Comment: did you try using string formatting on curr to make sure your strings are what you think they are?

Comment: @Tosh thanks for quick reply, what do you mean by String formatting?

Comment: basically do a bit of quick debugging, could be as simple as a few print statements to make sure the strings you think you are working with are the same as the strings the computer is passing around, and, if not, using something like string.format to make your string look the way you expect

Comment: just check if there is special character or space between the string for which you are searching for. debugging will also help.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. Fixed it by adding a marker for whether or not the statement was reached. `if(... name printed)`
         `...found = 1;`
       `else if(found != 1){`
         `System.out.println("Not found");`
         `break;`

Answer (score -4):

The return value is of type `boolean`. try to check with `true/false`

```
if(curr.contains(SocSec_input) == true){
}
```

and

```
else if(curr.contains(SocSec_input) == false){
}
```